# Is it possible to cast a constant reference as a pointer?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to cast a constant reference as a pointer, and if so how?

This is what I assume the cast should look like:

```
const TypeFoo &someVal;
TypeFoo *pSomePtr = reinterpret_cast<TypeFoo*>(someVal);
```

The example does not compile and I can't for the life of me understand why.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Why not `&someVal`?

Comment: Why are you doing ths?

Comment: I can't for the life of me understand why you expect it to *not* not compile. Did someone tell you "references are actually pointers"? If they did, don't trust them.

Comment: The variable someVal references the start of a block of memory, I want to iterate through that block of memory, I cannot do this using a reference. I am unsure whether what I am trying to do is even legal.

Comment: @BrendonAllan No, `someVal` references a variable. If you want the address of that variable, say that: `&someVal`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code:

```
const TypeFoo &someVal;
TypeFoo *pSomePtr = reinterpret_cast<TypeFoo*>(someVal);
```

This fails because you are missing the key point of references in C++, which can be summed up as:

**A reference *is* the object.**

A reference should not be viewed as kind of a special pointer. It does not point to anything. It is another name in the code. You are therefore trying to cast a `TypeFoo` to a pointer, which is not allowed, not even with `reinterpret_cast`. Your compiler should emit exactly the same error for the following code:

```
const TypeFoo someVal = /* ... */;
TypeFoo *pSomePtr = reinterpret_cast<TypeFoo*>(someVal); // error
```

If you need a `TypeFoo *`, then you can take the address of your object:

```
const TypeFoo &someVal = /* ... */;
const TypeFoo *pSomePtr = &someVal;
```

(Do not let the syntax confuse you. `&` serves completely different roles in these two lines of code.)

Note that the pointer has to be a pointer pointing to `const`, because the object is `const`, too. If you need a non-`const` pointer but have a `const` object, then you are facing an entirely new kind of problem, which may be solved with `const_cast` if you are lucky and are only dealing with a bad API, or may require a more radical redesign if the code you want to use needs to modify the object.

Furthermore, if you take the address of an object, then the usual caveats apply; most importantly, taking the address of a local object, keeping it around and dereferencing it later on, when the object has already been destroyed, causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, this has solved my problem and clarified my knowledge of pointers/references!

Comment: _"(Do not let the syntax confuse you. & serves completely different roles in these two lines of code.)"_ +1 for mentioning this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really sure you need to do this, rather use a `const_cast`:

```
 const TypeFoo &someVal = x; // lets assume it's initialized correctly
 TypeFoo *pSomePtr = const_cast<TypeFoo*>(&someVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues.  The first is that you can't have a reference that isn't initialized:

```
const TypeFoo &someVal;  // error
```

You need to have it reference something:

```
TypeFoo x;
const TypeFoo &someVal = x;
```

The next issue is that references and pointers are not interchangable.  Most likely what you meant to do was to take the address:

```
const TypeFoo *pSomePtr = &someVal;
```

The address of a reference is a pointer to the object it references.

Comment: I should have been more clear in my question, all variables are already initalised. You are correct, I did want the address of the object referenced. I never knew that references and pointers wern't interchangable.